# Hide page contents until filters are applied in WebBrowser Control

Tags: webbrowser-control, autohotkey

I'm modifying web contents displayed in a webbrowser control and looking for a way not to display them until all the changes are applied.

I'm currently using the DocumentComplete event and while filtering some pages, their contents are just visible. So I'd like to hide them until everything becomes okay to be shown.

**simple.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div>foo</div> bar</body>
</html>
```

**demo script**

```
new WBControl("file:///" A_ScriptDir "/simple.html")

class WBControl {

    DocumentComplete(oParams*) {
        doc :=  oParams[3].document
        sleep 200   ; simulate a delay caused by a heavy task
        doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.fontweight := "normal"
    }

    __New(strURL="") {
        static WB
        Gui, New, Resize MaximizeBox
        Gui, Add, ActiveX, vWB w780 h580, Shell.Explorer  
        Gui, show, w800 h600
        ComObjConnect(WB, this)
        WB.Navigate(strURL)
    }   
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.body.style.visibility := "hidden"
```

To restore visibility, set it to an empty string.

```
document.body.style.visibility := ""
```

You could also create a simple loading display to show instead; if you want to be fancy.

Comment: Not working here. Before `doc.body.style.visibility := "hidden` is applied, the original source is shown.